# How to display items of a list on separate lines in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, formatting, kivy, newline

I am writing a simple dictionary program using Python 3 and kivy.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def define(self, w):
        with open('data.json') as dict_file:
            data = json.load(dict_file)
        for number, meaning in enumerate(data[w]):
            return str(number + 1) + ') ' + meaning

    def show_meaning(self, w):
        with open('data.json') as dict_file:
            data = json.load(dict_file)
        w = w.casefold()
        if w in data.keys():
            self.ids.meaning.text = f"{self.define(w)}"
            print("Meaning printed")
        elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys(), cutoff=0.8)) > 0:
            d = enumerate(get_close_matches(w, data.keys(), cutoff=0.7))
            self.ids.meaning.text = f"Did you mean this/any of these?\n{[(number + 1, name) for number, name in d]}"
            time.sleep(3)
        elif w == '' or w == ' ' or w == '  ' or w == '   ' or w == '    ' or w == '     ' or w == '      ':
            self.ids.meaning.text = "Please enter something"
        else:
            self.ids.meaning.text = "Double check the word or try another word."
```

This is the main portion of the program. The dictionary **"data"** has multiple keys each having a value which is a list containing single or multiple definitions of the word. If a word has more than one meaning, a list is returned and *I want to return each meaning(item of the list) on a different line*. But if a for loop is used, it returns only the first meaning(item of the list) and breaks, thus not returning the second or further outputs. How can I overcome this problem? Please suggest a solution.

Following is the Kivy code:

```
<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Dictionary"
            font_size: "40sp"
        TextInput:
            id: word
            hint_text: "Enter a word to know its meaning"
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                id: meaning
                text: ""
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
        Button:
            text: "Enter"
            on_press: root.show_meaning(root.ids.word.text)
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.5, 'center_y': 0.6}

<RootWidget>:
    MainScreen:
        name: "main_screen"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in the `define()` method:

```
    for number, meaning in enumerate(data[w]):
        return str(number + 1) + ') ' + meaning
```

does not actually loop, but returns on the first entry in your `data`.
Try something like:

```
    defs = []
    for number, meaning in enumerate(data[w]):
        defs.append(str(number + 1) + ') ' + meaning + '\n')
    return ''.join(defs)
```